# How do i keep myself DRY and prevent code explosion in this scenario

Tags: java, flash, jsf

My application lets a user browse a world map. When the user clicks on a country, a mindmap appears. The user then traverses the nodes of this mindmap. So for example, when user clicks Singapore, a mind map appears. Next, the user clicks on a job function, e.g. Human Resources. This final node redirects the user to another page, in which there is a JSF datatable showing the job profiles in the respective location and function. A typical method which corresponds to each datatable looks like this.

```
    public ResultSet getAll() throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    try {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM JOBPROFILE WHERE LOCATION='SINGAPORE' AND JOBFUNCTION='HUMAN RESOURCES'");
        CachedRowSet crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
        crs.populate(result);
        return crs;
    } finally {
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have 16 locations and 14 functions. This means that I have **224** pages,datatables & methods to write! Maintenance would be a nightmare. Is there some way I could do this programatically so I wouldn't have to repeat most of the code over and over again? The only variance between each method is the SQL query. I'm implementing the world map and mind map in flash, hence I'm not sure as to how can I retrieve the final value the user clicks, and pass it to the backing bean,so that I can call the relevant query, instead of writing 224 different pages, datatables and methods which varies in only one line of code.

Comment: Can't you make the flash load a page with two parameters, one for location and one for jobfunction, which are then used by the page to execute the right query?

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about. I'm using two different flash libraries, ammap and freemind flash browser. The first one, has a function which returns the country clicked, but that is inside a javascript block, so I don't know how to pass that value to JSF. The second one, has no such functions. I embed a hyperlink in the mindmap which the user clicks on to be redirected to the respective page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the data in the hyperlink. i.e.

```
foo.com/jobs?country=singapore&jobfunction=humanresources
```

The JSF can then take that and call a more resuable method:

```
public ResultSet getAll(String location, String profile) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    try {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM JOBPROFILE WHERE LOCATION='"+location+"' AND JOBFUNCTION='"profile"'");
        CachedRowSet crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
        crs.populate(result);
        return crs;
    } finally {
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

Just remember that you should be escaping these or, better yet, using a [prepared statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: I had a somewhat similar solution. When the user clicks on the node, I could retrieve the view id (url). Using some string manipulation ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889321/how-do-i-split-this-string-using-regex-in-java ) , I retrieved the location and function and used prepared statement to render the relevant data table. Thanks anyway Jim!